# Can Castle ActiveRecord open a stateless session?

Tags: session, castle-activerecord, stateless

Real simply question: can Castle ActiveRecord open a stateless session? If so, how would I do it? And if not, how would I go about opening a stateless session without it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StatelessSessionScope` does the trick. It's part of [AR 2.1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/castleproject/files/)

Comment: Thanks! Now I just have to wait until the stable is released :).

Comment: StatelessSessionScope is actually in RC 2.0 (the stable version available from their main page): http://www.castleproject.org/castle/download.html  

Are they making significant changes to it in 2.1?

Comment: Krsysztof, is there any single sample over the internet about StatelessSessionScope usage? I did not find it neither on CastleProject site nor in Google!